# Strip "/" from the beginning and the end of my URI

Tags: php

So I have a URI that is returned like so /intelliship/ I need the beginning slash and trailing slash to be removed from that URI.

Attempted (FAILED) code:

```
<?php 
$value = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
function __construct($value){
    if(strpos($value,'/')==FALSE){
        return trim(substr(strrchr($value, ' '), 1 ));
    }else{
        return trim(substr($value, strpos($value,'/')),'/');
    }

    $value = ucwords($value);
}
?>
```

This doesn't strip any slashes and is pretty sloppy code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do it with regex, yes, but first learn to solve it properly with simple string functions. It's not that complicated

Comment: @Bergi that comment provides no real value or information...

Comment: Why not? It comments on your motivation to use regex, which is disputable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just:

```
$value = trim($value, "/");
```

There is no need for regex or checking what is the first or last character.